# How to replace tabs with spaces in Atom?

Tags: replace, indentation, atom-editor

As I started working with Atom text editor, I used tab-indentation but want to change to 4-space-indentation.

I have several files that should be updated accordingly

What would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: This is also the answer to "How to automatically convert all tabs in my Python file to spaces" _kinda solves the indentation error_

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Atom has a built-in tool for this

Activate the command palette (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux) and search for "convert space" or "convert tab". You should find these three commands are available:

- Whitespace: Convert Spaces to Tabs
- Whitespace: Convert Tabs to Spaces
- Whitespace: Convert All Tabs to Spaces

### Convert Tabs vs. Convert All Tabs

In the comments you observed that using "Convert Tabs to Spaces" would break indentation in Python, but "Convert **All** Tabs to Spaces" worked correctly. You asked what the difference between the two is.

I didn't know the answer, so I went looking. This is defined in the "whitespace" package, the source for which can be found on Github at [atom/whitespace](https://github.com/atom/whitespace).

Looking in [lib/whitespace.js](https://github.com/atom/whitespace/blob/master/lib/whitespace.js), I found this:

```coffeescript
'whitespace:convert-tabs-to-spaces': () => {
  let editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()

  if (editor) {
    this.convertTabsToSpaces(editor)
  }
},

'whitespace:convert-spaces-to-tabs': () => {
  let editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()

  if (editor) {
    return this.convertSpacesToTabs(editor)
  }
},

'whitespace:convert-all-tabs-to-spaces': () => {
  let editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()

  if (editor) {
    return this.convertTabsToSpaces(editor, true)
  }
}
```

As you can see, the relevant function here is `convertTabsToSpaces`. In the "convert all" variant, the only difference is that a second (optional) argument is passed, and set to `true`.

```coffeescript
return this.convertTabsToSpaces(editor, true)
```

Looking at the definition of `convertTabsToSpaces`, the difference is that the regex is changed based on the state of this boolean argument.

```coffeescript
convertTabsToSpaces (editor, convertAllTabs) {
  let buffer = editor.getBuffer()
  let spacesText = new Array(editor.getTabLength() + 1).join(' ')
  let regex = (convertAllTabs ? /\t/g : /^\t+/g)

  buffer.transact(function () {
    return buffer.scan(regex, function ({replace}) {
      return replace(spacesText)
    })
  })

  return editor.setSoftTabs(true)
}
```

The relevant line here is:

```coffeescript
let regex = (convertAllTabs ? /\t/g : /^\t+/g)
```

So in the "convert all" variant, the regex does not care about being anchored to the beginning of the line (`^` is not used), and each tab is is own replacement (rather than groups of tab characters being treated as a single replacement -- `\t` vs. `\t+`).

### Why it broke Python indentation

I don't know what file you used, but I used a pretty simple test file like this, indented completely with tab characters.

```py
import foo

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = True

    def bar(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

After using "Convert Tabs to Spaces" it looked like this:

```py
import foo

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
    self.foo = True

    def bar(self, a, b):
    return a + b
```

Woah! That's now a `SyntaxError`. Try again with "Convert **All** Tabs to Spaces":

```py
import foo

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = True

    def bar(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

This happens because in the first case, groups of tabs on the left margin are, *as a collection*, reduced to a space-based indent. Since the regex is `^\t+`, it doesn't matter if the line is indented with 1, 2, 8, 24 tabs... they are all replaced with a single indent level, but made of spaces.

Honestly I don't know what the point of that is... that seems like a bug.

In the second case, every tab is converted to the equivalent space-based width (i.e. each tab is converted into 4 spaces, even if it is adjacent to another tab character).

So that's the one you probably want.

One caveat: it is no longer limited to the left margin (there is no `^` anchor), so if you have embedded tab characters elsewhere, those will also be converted. That is not a normal practice in code in my experience, but FYI, in case it matters to you.

Comment: Very straightforward! Just one note: `Whitespace: Convert Tabs to Spaces` removes all indentations, at least for `python` files. `Whitespace: Convert Spaces to Tabs` and `Whitespace: Convert All Tabs to Spaces` are the ones that work as expected for me.

Comment: @J0ANMM Wow, you are right... for me it did not remove all indent in a sample file, but it did _break_ the indent level. That really seems like a bug. I might file an Atom bug, if I can figure out what the underlying behavior is...

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I did not describe it correctly. What is supposed to be the difference between `Convert Tabs` and `Convert All Tabs`?

Comment: @J0ANMM Good question... went looking into this and I added my findings about it to my answer.

Answer (score 16):

A simple solution I found after some research is using the "Replace All" tool.

Just open each file, and then open the Find Panel (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> in Mac).

[image: Screenshot showing replacement of tabs by spaces]

Find in current buffer (with `use regex` option activated):

```
\t
```

Replace in current buffer:

```
    #that being just four spaces
```

Comment: '\t' doesn't find any tabs even when the "use regex" option is checked, when there are clearly tabs in the document.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem where it will not find \t after I put 20 tabs in the file deliberately.

Comment: Make sure you press the 'Find' or 'Find all' button, as it does not automatically find the regex tabs while typing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the proper tabs, you need to specify the length, otherwise it will also match single spaces between words.

Press **ctrl+F** and enter *[ \t]{4}* on the first line and *4 spaces* on the second line
[image: ctrl-f]

Afterwards I will also recommend installing the package *python-indent* to handle the indentation according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Packages <kbd>-></kbd> Whitespace <kbd>-></kbd> Convert All Tabs To Spaces

Answer (score 0):

Packages -> Whitespace -> Convert All Tabs To Spaces

Comment: Please do not add things like "this answer works for me" as separate answers.